# Aplicar FILTER_SANITIZE ou real_escape_string em todos os campos de um json

Tags: php

Bom tenho que aplicar um `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS` em dodos os campos de um json.

Atualmente recebe o json assim:

```
// Recebo o json
$json = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'json', FILTER_DEFAULT);

// Decodifica o Json
$obj = json_decode($json);

// Aqui eu tenho que aplicar o `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`
```

O var_dump do json:

```
{
 "Autenticacao": {
    "login": "100",
    "senha": "123"
 },
 "operacao": {
    "nome": "hugo",
    "endereco": "rua sei la",
    "numero": "123"
 }
}
```

Como navegar pelo campos `login`,`senha`,`nome`,`endereco` e `numero` aplicando o `FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS`?

Edite ----------------------------

Tentei com o `real_escape_string` da seguinte forma:

```
foreach ($obj as &$main) {
            foreach ($main as &$value) {
                $value = $conexao->real_escape_string($value);
            }
        }
```

Porém estou tendo esse erro:

```
mysqli::real_escape_string() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
```

Comment: como é para todos os campos aplica um foreach duplo , e depois so filtrares as strings

Comment: tas a passar um objeto como parâmetro

Comment: @13dev Entendi, tenho que navegar dentro do objeto para aplicar o `real_escape_string`, certo?

Comment: sim claro tenta fazer `print_r()` no `$value` para acessares corretamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usando dois `foreach`s e adicione o `&` ("E" comercial) as **variáveis de valor** do `foreach` para criar uma referencia:

```
foreach ($obj as &$main) {
    foreach ($main as &$value) {
        $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    }
}
```

Veja o o que ocorre se usar INT em um dos campos e booleano em outro no jsfiddle: https://ideone.com/5hVH3d, código:

```
<?php

$obj = json_decode('{
 "Autenticacao": {
    "login": 100000000000,
    "senha": "123"
 },
 "operacao": {
    "nome": false,
    "endereco": "rua sei la",
    "numero": "123"
 }
}');

foreach ($obj as &$main) {
    foreach ($main as &$value) {
        $value = filter_var($value, FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
    }
}

var_dump($obj);
```

O campo nome vira uma string vazia e o campo login vira uma string em formato de numero, mas deixou de ser do tipo "int", **veja o resultado** do `var_dump($obj);` os campos foram alterados diretamente no `$obj`:

```
object(stdClass)#2 (2) {
  ["Autenticacao"]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (2) {
    ["login"]=>
    string(12) "100000000000" <--------- AQUI
    ["senha"]=>
    string(3) "123"
  }
  ["operacao"]=>
  &object(stdClass)#3 (3) {
    ["nome"]=>
    string(0) "" <--------- AQUI
    ["endereco"]=>
    string(10) "rua sei la"
    ["numero"]=>
    &string(3) "123"
  }
}
```

A alteração afetou **diretamente as variável** `$obj` devido ao **e-comerical**, conforme a documentação do PHP:

- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.whatare.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.whatdo.php
- http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.references.arent.php

### Com mysql e real_escape

Você pode fazer assim:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

...

foreach ($obj as &$main) {
    foreach ($main as &$value) {
        $value = $mysqli->real_escape_string($value);
    }
}
```

Se for procedural:

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "usuario", "senha", "banco");

...

foreach ($obj as &$main) {
    foreach ($main as &$value) {
        $value = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $value);
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, mas com faço para alterar o objeto que esta com o json? No caso o `$obj`.

Comment: @HugoBorges com o E comercial, como esta no exemplo `($obj as &$main)` e `($main as &$value)`

Comment: @HugoBorges editei a resposta para entender melhor.

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado. é possível fazer usando o `real_escape_string`? Editei minha pergunta.

Comment: @HugoBorges seria melhor usar prepared_statment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @HugoBorges editei a resposta, veja exemplos com real_escape

Comment: Da sua forma esta dando esse erro`Warning: mysqli_real_escape_string() expects exactly 2 parameters, 1 given in` estou tentando usar o `mysqli_real_escape_string($value)`

Comment: @HugoBorges corrigido, editei a pergunta

Answer (score 2):

Para esta pergunta decidi fazer uma pequena função, que so funciona se o json tiver só 1 grau mas resolve bem a situação.

**OBS** a variável é passada por referencia o que quer dizer que será alterada,não precisas de fazer `$json = saveJson($obj);`

**OBS** O filtro atual é **FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING** , **[escolhe um que encaixe as tuas necessidades](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php)**

```
function saveJson(&$json)
{
    foreach($json as $key => $object)
    {
        foreach($object as $key1 => $o)
        {
            $json->$key->$key1 = filter_var($o, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito bom, obrigado. é possível fazer usando o real_escape_string? Editei minha pergunta.

Comment: @HugoBorges Tenta usar [prepared statements](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) assim evitas usar `real_escape_string()`